# How do I sum a many to many value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, collect

Each User can have many Resources, and each of those Resources has many Votes, and each of those votes have a value attribute that I want to sum all that particular users resources.

If I were to type this in a syntactically incorrect way I want something like...

`@user.resources.votes.sum(&:value)`, but that obviously won't work.

I believe I need to use `collect` but I am not sure?

This is the closest I got but it prints them out, heh

`<%= @user.resources.collect { |r| r.votes.sum(&:value) } %>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can you tell who voted having a Vote instance? Your Vote model has to have `voter_id` field and additional association:

```
# in Vote.rb
belongs_to :voter, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'voter_id'
```

And in your User model:

```
# in User.rb
has_may :submited_votes, class_name: 'Vote', foreign_key: 'voter_id'
```

So, `@user.votes` (as David Underwood proposed) will give you @user resources' votes. And `@user.submited_votes` will give you votes submitted by the @user.

Using just User <- Resource <- Vote relation won't allow you to separate some user's votes made by him and votes made for its resources.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you mean. What I want to do is essentially sum = 0; @user.resources.each do { |resource| sum += resource.votes.sum(&:value) }

Comment: That code works but its too long, i just wanted to write it all on one line

Comment: If you have properly specified relationships then you'll be able to calc you sums by `@user.votes.sum(:value)`.

Comment: Isn't that going to find only votes with the user_id of @user?

Comment: Does your Vote have `user_id` field? You were telling that User connected with Vote model via Resource.

Comment: I have User, Resource and Vote. Each User has_many resources, and has_many votes. each Resource belongs_to user and has many_votes, each Vote belongs_to resource, and belongs_to user. Inside my Vote model i have resource_id and user_id. I want to basically say "first find every resource where :user_id => user.id, once you have those resources, run through them and find all votes where :resource_id => resource.id (not user.id), and for all those votes take a sum of those votes.value (its going to be 1, 0 or -1). That will be the persons overall score for all the resources they have submitted

Comment: If i go directly from User to votes, its going to show only votes where :user_id is the same as the users, which would mean it would talley only their own votes on other peoples posts. I want to talley the score of the resources that they have submitted (votes by all users, including their own)

Comment: That is my current understanding that is, not saying youre wrong im just clarifying what i know so far

Comment: [Couldn't edit, had to recreate. You were too fast at your comments so after posting my comment I realized that you'd had posted 2] *Each User ... has_many votes* -- this isn't clear from your question! I suggested to make the same thing! Now I see it more clearly. Looks like you need: `User.find(1).resources.joins(:votes).sum('votes.value')`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend setting up a `has_many :through` relationship between the User and Vote objects. Set the models up like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :resources
  has_many :votes, :through => :resources
end

class Resource < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :votes
end

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :resource
end
```

Once this is done you can simply call `user.votes` and do whatever you want with that collection.

For more info on `has_many :through` relations, see this guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, im not sure if what you said still applies. I do have a relationship but I'm trying to tally all the 'global' votes for all the resources submitted by a User(all the votes from other people on that persons resources). If i do User.votes it only talleys the votes created by that person

Answer (score 1):

For a total sum this should work or something real close.

```
sum = 0
@user.resources.each do |r|
r.votes.each do |v|
    sum += v.value
end
end
```

This might work for you:

```
@user.resources.map {|r| r.votes.sum(:value)}.sum
```

How many records do you have, there is a way to push this to the database level I believe, I would have to check, but if it is only a few records then doing this in ruby would probably be ok

Comment: that would work but i'm trying to fit it all on one line, ideally using some kind of Proc, just to keep this portion of my code clean

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
@user.resources.map(&:votes).flatten.map(&:value).sum
```

Comment: Effective, but possibly disastrous on he SQL called, no?